# Dynamic website in php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, dynamic, web

i have created a generic template which should display the content of the parameter being passed in the URL by fetching details from the database.

Ex.
Home page: **index.php**
Template: **Pages.php**
link displayed on Home page: "**This is fetched from Database**"
when clicked it should navigate to: **Pages.php/This is fetched from Database** (this is the parameter passed to the database to get the content)

This is working properly but when the i click Home (index.php) in **Pages.php/This is fetched from Database** the same is being treated as Pages.php/index.php but it should go to index.php directly.

I have used htaccess for rewriting the url but it didnt workout.

Basically i am building a dynamic website and my question is how can i effectively use the generic template concept for achieving the dynamic website?

The code i used for getting this **Pages.php/This is fetched from Database**

```
<?php    
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12345", "dbname");    
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];    
$uri = $uri[4];    
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title FROM Posts where Title = $uri");    
echo "<a href = '"./pages.php/{$row["Title"]}."' alt = "">{$row["Title"]}
</a>";    
?>
```

Comment: `$uri` is a string; treat it as such. What you have now `where Title = $uri` will fail you.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. This is not a constructive remark, but it has to be said: there is so much wrong with this code I wouldn't know where to start. Please read up on HTML, PHP and SQL injection.

Comment: `$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` ... ok let's assume *"/index.php"*. `$uri = $uri[4];` erm - so now `$uri = "e"` ? I'm betting that's not what you wanted... now that means your select is `SELECT Title FROM Posts where Title = e` < well, that's blown it since "e" isn't a number; what's the point anyway, that's like saying *"Yo dawg, I heard you like "e" so SELECT "e" WHERE "e" = "e"* ... the mind boggles.

Comment: i am not a PHP guy, my core technology is completely different. i am doing this website for my own interest. However thanks for your suggestions i will try the same.

Answer (score 0):

The relative URL `index.php` means:

1. Take the URL of the current page
2. Remove everything after the path
3. Remove everything **after the last `/`**
4. Append something to it

If you don't want to keep everything in the path that is before the last `/`, then you need to link to `/index.php` and not `index.php`.

Answer (score -2):

You can do some search on **php design patterns** to have better idea about what you try to achieve .

Here is somewhere you can start from :

[simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/)

For your code ,

```
$uri = $uri[4];
```

**$uri** is a string  not an array , so the above line will only get the character on the 4th position  , try to remove that line and test .

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: surprise ! after editing -2 found , sorry for that .

Comment: @jirarium Thanks for the advise and thanks for the tutorial:)

Comment: @Hari , glad it helped ; )